# Have my url as openid

Tags: openid

How can I use my domain `mydomainname.com` as an OpenID?

I have a Blogger URL with OpenID and can sign in with that.

I made an account with myOpenID for `mydomainname` and replaced `myaccountname` with `youraccount` in their given code in `<head>`, but it's still not working.

What else is required?

```
  <link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
  <link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://youraccount.myopenid.com/" />
  <link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://youraccount.myopenid.com" />
  <link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://www.myopenid.com/xrds?username=youraccount.myopenid.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at your website, and I see the following HTML:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://technispace.com/" />
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://technispace.com" />
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://www.myopenid.com/xrds?username=technispace.com" />
```

This is not quite right; you should have `http://technispace.myopenid.com/` as the `openid.delegate` and `openid2.local_id`, and the "username" in the last tag should be just `technispace`, not `technispace.com`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for answering, I had done same thing before but could not sign in with url later did this change which you found out.